# Frame on images and buttons

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set my buttons and images to be in a specific spot on all Iphone screen sizes. Normally I would use `CGPoint(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)` , but in buttons you use .Frame which is different, and I write `.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width / 7.7, y: self.frame.height / 2.6, width: self.frame.width / 10, height: self.frame.height / 12)`

, but it works on one screen for say iphone 6, but then on a iphone 5 it is in a different spot... any suggestions??

Comment: In which method did you set your frame ?

Comment: what do you mean? @MaulikBhuptani